# Request Dialog - JavaScript Example - Does not work in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am following the example in the [facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

It works fine in Chrome, but for some reason, when i run the same code in Internet explorer, I get a Javascript error.

I want to allow users of my app to send invites to use the application.

Anyone else have this problem or have a workaround?

Here are my error details (well what i could get anyway):

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; FDM) Timestamp: Tue, 27 Sep 2011 18:09:30 UTC
>
> Message: Expected identifier, string or number Line: 38 Char: 9 Code:
>   0 URI: `http://someplace:5000/InviteFriends2.aspx`
>
> Message: Object expected Line: 20 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI: (same as above 
>   URI)

---

Answer (score 2):

They have trailing commas in the examples which is not a good thing to do. Remove them.

```
  function sendRequestToOneRecipient() {
    var user_id = document.getElementsByName("user_id")[0].value;
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
      to: user_id,   <-- Trailing comma
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request', <-- Trailing comma
    }, requestCallback);
  }
```

Comment: Lol, thanks guy :-)

Was coming back to update my answer to that exact found issue.  

Yeah agreed, for people new to this, their examples should be perfect. But then again, so should my Javascript if I want to use this SDK :-)

TX!

Comment: Trailing commas are now gone :)